# How do I a generate a list of edges from a given list of vertex indices?

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, rendering, polygon

I have a face-vertex mesh like the following image has.

[Face-Vertex Mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyamf.png)
[image]

I have 'face_list' and 'vertex_list' data sets, but not sure how to efficiently calculate a list of edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the normal vectors of the faces. If the normal vectors of 2 adjacent faces point in different directions, the two vertices shared by the face form an edge.

The normal vectors of a face can be computed with the [Cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). For a face with the vertices A, B, C, the [unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) normal vector is:

```
N = normalized(cross(B-A, C-A))
```

The normal vectors of the faces can be compared with the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). 2 normal vectors N1 and N2 are equal directed if:

```
equally_directed = abs(dot(N1, N2)) == 1
```

Use a library for the vector arithmetic. For example [OpenGL Mathematics (GLM) library for Python](https://pypi.org/project/PyGLM/) or [NumPy](https://numpy.org/).

---

Minimal example:

```py
import glm, math

vertices = [(-1,-1,-1), ( 1,-1,-1), ( 1, 1,-1), (-1, 1,-1), (-1,-1, 1), ( 1,-1, 1), ( 1, 1, 1), (-1, 1, 1)]
faces = [(0,1,2), (0,2,3), (5,4,7), (5,7,6), (4,0,3), (4,3,7), (1,5,6), (1,6,2), (4,5,1), (4,1,0), (3,2,6), (3,6,7)]

v = [glm.vec3(vertex) for vertex in vertices]
nv_list = [glm.normalize(glm.cross(v[i1]-v[i0], v[i2]-v[i0])) for i0,i1,i2 in faces]

edge_threshold = 0.99
edges = []
for i, f1 in enumerate(faces):
    for j, f2 in enumerate(faces[i+1:]):
        edge_candidates = [(f1[0], f1[1]), (f1[1], f1[2]), (f1[2], f1[0])]
        for ei0, ei1 in edge_candidates:
            if ei0 in f2 and ei1 in f2:
                cos_nv = math.fabs(glm.dot(nv_list[i], nv_list[j+i+1]))
                if  abs(cos_nv) < edge_threshold:
                    edges.append((ei0, ei1))

print(len(edges))
print(edges)
```

Output:

> ```
> 12
> [(1, 2), (0, 1), (3, 0), (2, 3), (4, 7), (5, 4), (6, 5), (7, 6), (4, 0), (3, 7), (1, 5), (6, 2)]
> ```